# Intents inside a Recycler View?

Tags: android, android-intent, onclick, android-5.0-lollipop, android-recyclerview

Could anyone help me out! Cant get the normal way of writing intent to launch a new activity inside my recycler view to work! Is there a new way you must do it? Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Here is my View Holder Code;

```
    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    TextView title;
    ImageView icon;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView, TextView textView) {
        super(itemView);
        title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.listText);
        icon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.listImage);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        title = textView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (getPosition() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Actvity 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if (getPosition() == 1) {
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Actvity 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Initial click listeners in your viewHolder.

```
/**
 * see {@link <a href="https://youtu.be/imsr8NrIAMs?t=2163">Official Video</a>}
 */
public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

  public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    //TODO: findViewById or ButterKnife
    ....
    //set item view listener
    itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override public void onClick(View itemView) {
        if (getAdapterPosition() != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
          Context c = itemView.getContext();
          //TODO: startActivity
        }
      }
    });
    //TODO: set other child views' listener
    ....
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your custom adapter create your own constructor.
for Example:

```
  private Context context;
    public MyRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<String> yourList){
            this.context=context;
            // further code
    }
```

and while calling your adapter just pass the reference of your context and now you can able to call intent via

`context.startActivity()` & all other methods.

Answer (score 0):

The `ViewHolder` is just a container for the inner `View` objects within your specific layout for the item.  Neither it or the `RecyclerView.Adapter` for your implementation have direct access to the `Context` object needed to send an `Intent`.  Rather than set your `OnClickListener` here, put it in your adapter's `onBindViewHolder()`.  Your adapter can be notified when its owning `RecyclerView` is attached to it, so you can save a reference to it in a private field.  From that view you can call `getContext()` so you could then create an `Intent` and send it via the usual means.

Comment: ViewHolder has access to the root View,  so it has access to the Context as well

Comment: Ah, you're right, I'd forgotten that detail.  I usually leave it to the Adapter or the owning Fragment (using an interface) to deal with the click/touch interactions than put it here in the holder.